# "Quality Standards" error not very useful?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, error-message

Inspired by *[Can anyone PLEASE tell me how I can ask questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376458/2191572)*, I tried to figure out exactly what error the user could have possibly encountered.

Lo and behold

[image]

Should the red box go somewhere?

Comment: This is intriguing, in spite of being a low-bar wall against bad questions. Any cheap workaround might send the false impression that the question will not be closed/downvoted eventually (since apparently it overcame that "quality standards" barrier).

Comment: It's...not supposed to be that helpful, I think.  All people will do if it's clickable is do the bare minimum to pass the bar, and post.  It's a good indicator that trying to bypass it will lead to a bad reception.  Less focus on specific issues, and more general, "This needs to be, overall, better than it is."

Comment: If you get a prompt to "add more text" (I don't know the exact words, never having had that problem), then choose: (a) explain what the problem is, or why your code does not work, or how, *or* (b) add [the first 500 words of a lorem ipsum generator](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53205916/1). (Edited out in the mean time; what's left is, predictably, not a stellar question.)

Comment: I thought buttons that don't look like buttons, and not-buttons that look like buttons, are SO standard?

Comment: By this time, a new user has already ignored *many* hints about how to write a question.  I think the best outcome is probably for them to go find someplace else to ask their "question."

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Very observant but I did not come here to pick a fight and bare-knuckle box over that age-old problem. I am more so pointing out the UX blasphemy being committed by providing a non-actionable error message as described in my comment here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376461/quality-standards-error-not-very-useful#comment645655_376464

Comment: I mean, it's kind of not a very nice not-button, isn't it? "Your post isn't good enough for this site. But we're not going to tell you what you did wrong. Nyah." (I too have given up on getting SO to do good UI/UX. I was being kind of cavalier in my initial comment.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I am aware of your comment's cavalierness. I support it but at this time I am not going up to bat for it :-)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas At the risk of sounding unwelcoming, I'm interpreting this dialog as "Your post isn't good enough for this site.  If you can't figure out why you're getting this error message on your own, *please go away*."  Individuals who can't figure out what they're doing wrong are *very* unlikely to formulate a good question.

Comment: Flat "design" fails [again](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/flat-design-long-exposure/)...

Answer (score 8):

- There's a link to the help center's section on how to ask questions on the right.
- They were shown information on how to ask questions and required to acknowledge that they read it before being allowed to ask their first question.
- There's a help center link in the top right of every page.
- (And most importantly) If I need to tell you why that's a bad question, there's an inherent problem here.  Anyone should be able to tell why that's a bad question.  If you're seriously going to tell me that you don't know why that question might be bad or how it could possibly be improved, then honestly, I consider you beyond hope and feel that no amount of information could be presented to you that would allow you to post a useful question.

  This error exists for question that really are *that* bad.  It's not there for questions with a few typos, or something that you could have just searched, or something that's a bit unclear.

Comment: I think it's quite obvious that **I** know what's going on and where to look but if we take a step back and consider good UX rules; an error message which expects action from the user should empower the user to take said action. Additionally, my screenshot is over 1477px tall which far exceeds the average monitor height so the useful information and links would likely be out of view by the time they see an error.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus When I said "you" I was referring to anyone seeing that error, not just "MonkeyZeus".  *Anyone* writing that question should be able to tell that it's a bad question.  If they can't, no amount of help the site can provide is going to be of use.

Comment: I agree with the answer here but anymore I believe errors like this are actually doing neither side any favors.

Comment: Presumably the trigger in my example was that the body had code only, correct? Pretend for a moment that the title asked a coherent question and the body had all relevant code with comments; they would honestly be a small step away from posting a proper question. Also, DV not mine since you fairly presented the logic behind the current implementation.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Having a bunch of code and no question is more than just a small step away from posting a proper question.

Comment: @Servy I am not suggesting that the error be changed to "Add some non-code body text to continue." but maybe it should just link to a "How to ask" resource.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus They've been linked to it numerous times in the past, there are several links to it on that page, and given that they're at this point, the odds of the how to ask actually being able to help them are so low (given how far they are from asking a good question), that I don't think it's useful to try to worry about adding *more* links.  People who would be helped by reading it wouldn't get to that point, people getting to that point won't read it.  There are better things to spend time on then helping the hopeless.

Comment: @Servy I've got to agree with MonkeyZeus that it is possible, in principle, to write a good question with little or no prose in the question body. Sometimes there isn't much to say beyond what's in the title, and sometimes it's a good stylistic choice to write most or all of the prose you do have as code comments. I don't think either of those things is the norm, but I don't think they're so profoundly impossible that it's right to block such questions without even giving a hint about what the "problem" is.

Comment: @MarkAmery But we're not "not giving them a hint".  They were shown the help center before they could get to that point, there are still two links to it right on that page.  They can still get to the information on how to ask a good question if they really are looking for it.

Comment: @Servy Hmm - and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask *does* indeed demand a paragraph of prose prior to the first appearance of any code in a question. I still disagree with that as a universal rule, and think that it's a weak defence of the lack of a detailed message to argue that somebody who has posted a question that hits the filter (perhaps a good, clear question whose narrative just happens to be presented as a sequence of commented lines of code) can in principle read that page and deduce how they should mangle their question to bypass the quality filter.